# Entity Framework Code First Error "Error Locating Server/Instance Specified"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I'm trying to use Code First with my local instance of Sql Server 2008 R2. I've create a user 'dev' and can log in and create databases using Sql Managment Studio. The problem is I keep getting an error message when trying to create a database using DbContext in EntityFramework. Here is the error message:

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified"

The error message I checked my Sql Server and it does allow remote connections.

I've abstracted my system with the following code and get the same error:

```
namespace CodeFirstConsole
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var db = new MyContext();
            try { Console.WriteLine(db.Parents.Count()); }
            catch (Exception) { throw; }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    internal class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ParentObject> Parents { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ChildObject> Children { get; set; }

        public MyContext()
        {
            this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString =
                "Data Source=.;Database=ConsoleTest;Initial Catalog=ConsoleTest;User ID=dev;Password=dev;";
        }
    }

    internal class ParentObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
    }

    internal class ChildObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool PropertyOne { get; set; }
        public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }

        public virtual ParentObject Parent { get; set; }
    }

    internal class MyInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>
    {

        protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
        {
            context.Parents.Add(new ParentObject() { PropertyOne = "hi" });
            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried explicitly specifying the datasource, I know if you leave it blank it thinks its the same machine but try putting it in and ways and see if you get the same results.

Comment: Yes, I've explicitly specified it in my example when I set the connection string.

Comment: Just checking obviously the code above that you have written also sits on the SQL Server machine you are connecting to right? Just checking.

Comment: Checkout the link I have posted for you in the answers section. Also you might want to check named pipes settings also (just to verify)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had the same error that drove me nuts for about a day. My situation was I had a large solution with a pre-existing start-up project and I was adding EF to the persistence project.

So the first step was to add the EF dependency. This created an app.config in my persistence project with the correct EF content. Then I went to Enable-Migrations and got the same error in this post. At this point I didn't think of copying the EF app.config settings to the app.config of the start-up project since I thought I'd have to play around with it before I would eventually run the app.

The problem was resolved when I changed the solution start-up project to the persistence project so I could get EF to find the correct app.config. Or I could have copied the EntityFramwework related section to the app.config of the start-up project.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was banging my head against this.

Comment: This answer probably just saved my hours! Thank you

Comment: Start-up project...! You deserve a hug!

Comment: I know this is old, but I wanted to thank you! I tried everything I could think of... nothing worked... right-click project > set as startup... everything's working great lol. I feel stupid lol.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error message developing on local, but it worked fine yesterday.
Turns out the wrong project in the solution was set as the StartUp Project.

So if you are also getting this message after an update-database command in the Package Manager Console, be sure to check if the correct StartUp Project is set.

For example the Web project, and not one of the helper projects.
Visual studio seems to have the habit of setting other projects as the StartUp by itself sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look here it explains a lot of the causes, since you indicated in the comments that you did explicitly specify server name and the code runs also on the same machine as sql server since from what I see the datasource just has a dot, indicating that its the same machine as the c# code program running on.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Had to add the EntityFramework dependency also to the startup project.

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```

And also had to define `connectionStrings` to my main project App.config/Web.config.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Database" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="foo.bar" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here was a solution for me
[Traditional SqlClient can find server instance but EF can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26263852/traditional-sqlclient-can-find-server-instance-but-ef-cant)

In short:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(
new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Migrations.Configuration>(
    useSuppliedContext: true));
```

Main part here is **useSuppliedContext: true**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and spent a whole day on it. Finally found @Christian's answer and now I find a much better way!

Put `ConnectionString` in the startup project. So you don't need to switch every time you change an entity.