# Traditional SqlClient can find server instance but EF can't

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm having a problem that I've been beating my head over for a while now and I'm hoping someone who knows more about this than I do can answer it.

Part of my application uses the traditional System.Data.SqlClient stuff to connect to one database and another part uses Entity Framework to connect to a different database on the same SQL server using these two connection strings:

```
var connectionString = 
    "Server=SERVER\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Database1;User=myUser;Password=myPass;";

var efConnectionString = 
    "Server=SERVER\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Database2;User=myUser;Password=myPass;";
```

With the non-EF part of my application I can hit the database just fine. But when I try to do anything with the EF part I get an exception saying it can't find the SQL Server instance:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

**I've triple-checked that there are no typos in the EF connection string** and even had a couple co-workers re-check it. I also checked the `context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString` property to make sure it was using the right connection string and it is.

This really doesn't making any sense. What would cause EF to not find the SQL Server when every other method I've tried can?

#### Update

My context looks like this:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() { }
    public MyContext(string connString) : base(connString) { }
    ...
}
```

I always construct using the overloaded constructor that accepts a connection string:

```
var context = new MyContext(efConnectionString);
```

I even removed the default constructor and built the project just to make sure it wasn't being used anywhere else.

Comment: myUser does not have rights to Database2?

Comment: I already checked that too. :( I believe the exception would be different if that were the case.

Comment: Can you use efConnectionString in some plain old System.Data.SqlClient stuff and see if it connects through that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the problem!

I am using code first in this application. In the startup code I set the initializer to a new `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initializer:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(
    new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Migrations.Configuration>());
```

When the database is initialized it instantiates a new `MyContext` using the default constructor. So it's trying to connect to the default SQL instance (either LocalDb or SQLExpress) which doesn't exist on my server.

If I want to use the context with the correct connection string I can tell it to in `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`'s constructor:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(
    new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Migrations.Configuration>(
        useSuppliedContext: true));
```

This to me seems like it should be the default behavior. Why would the initializer need to create a new context if it is supplied one when it's run? Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

It could be an issue in the way you are constructing the context for Entity Framework. The constructor of the `DbContext` has an overload taking a `nameOrConnectionString` that can be provided with the name of a connection from the `<connectionStrings>` element of your config, or the full connection string. There is a default constructor as well which, if you're using it, will use conventions to look for the database. I think this looks in LocalDb (not SQLExpress) for a database with the same name as the name of the DbContext derived class.

Comment: I thought it might have something to do with this, but I always use the constructor that accepts a connection string. See the update to the question.